# AVAudioPlayer issue when playing cached mp3 file

Tags: ios, avaudioplayer

In my app ,I download a mp3 file to the Library/caches .
This file cannot be played by AVAudioPlayer with the FileURL,samleCode:

```
_audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:fileUrl error:&error];
            if (error) {
                NSLog(@"%@",[error localizedDescription]);
            }
            _audioPlayer.delegate = self;
            [_audioPlayer prepareToPlay];
            [_audioPlayer setNumberOfLoops:-1];
            [_audioPlayer play];
```

The URL is like this:
file://localhost/Users/*****/Library/Application%20Support/iPhone%20Simulator/4.3.2/Applications/1A41C5EE-04D3-4C95-BAFE-9B6E04535F8F/Library/Caches/etude.mp3

When start,this methods is called,- audioPlayerDecodeErrorDidOccur: error:.
description is:The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error 560100710.)
Google says nothing about this error code.

However this file can be played in iTunes and AVAudioPlayer when put in app Bundle.
I just can't figure it out.Can any one tell me how to fix it?

Comment: 4 yrs later, and that same error is lurking around iOS